# A way to change the shipping method of an Order

Tags: magento-1.8

Is there a way to change programmatically the shipping method and consequently the shipping prices associated to an existing Magento Order when the order was already placed ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this natively.

Well, yes, you *can* do this directly in the database via queries or via the Magento ORM.

However, this goes against the general ledger concepts modeled in Magento *and* **it is a violation of most (all?) payment processor terms**.